# Delete the 'first' record from a table in SQL Server, without a WHERE condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to delete the *first* record from a table in `SQL Server`, without using any `WHERE` condition and without using a cursor?

Answer (score 162, accepted):

```
WITH  q AS
        (
        SELECT TOP 1 *
        FROM    mytable
        /* You may want to add ORDER BY here */
        )
DELETE
FROM    q
```

Note that

```
DELETE TOP (1)
FROM   mytable
```

will also work, but, as stated in the [**documentation**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx):

> The rows referenced in the `TOP` expression used with `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` are not arranged in any order.

Therefore, it's better to use `WITH` and an `ORDER BY` clause, which will let you specify more exactly which row you consider to be the first.

Comment: Note that when using `WITH` in expression, previous sql statement should be terminated with semi-colon (;)

Comment: Using `ORDER BY 1` would offer a subtle improvement on many people's tables in SQL Server: you'd get the row with the lowest primary key value, likely to be the 'first' row. (True, some tables don't have the PK as the first column, but `1` is my favourite lazy shortcut and I wanted to share it.)

Comment: @MagnusSmith: improvement over what?

Comment: It was only a minor point. Your answer did not give a specific ORDER BY clause, and I realised the original poster had asked for the 'first' row whilst appearing to be unable to specify a column name. This made me think of using `1`.

Comment: @MagnusSmith: ah ok, though it's always better to specify the column named explicitly.

Comment: The greatest Thing about this is, you can also combine the `delete Top (1) `with a Where-Clause, so you can delete duplicate-rows.

Comment: I tried this on SQLSERVER 2000 and didnt work ;( .... i supouse it is because is and old version

Comment: @CésarLeón CTE are only supported since 2008. Not that it's any of my business but given that it's 2018 now I would really consider upgrading!

Comment: @Quassnoi is not my call... that is the company i work for. I also would like to be able to change the world XD

Answer (score 55):

depends on your [DBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dbms)

```
-- MYSql:
DELETE FROM table LIMIT 1;
-- Postgres:
DELETE FROM table LIMIT 1;
-- MSSql:
DELETE TOP(1) FROM table;
-- Oracle:
DELETE FROM table WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

Comment: Oracle's one violates "without ... where" restriction (whatever is the purpose of said restriction).

Answer (score 5):

No, AFAIK, it's not possible to do it portably.

There's no defined "first" record anyway - on different SQL engines it's perfectly possible that "`SELECT * FROM table`" might return the results in a different order each time.

Answer (score 3):

Define "First"? If the table has a PK then it will be ordered by that, and you can delete by that:

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Data NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO @TABLE(Data)
SELECT 'Hello' UNION
SELECT 'World' 

SET ROWCOUNT 1
DELETE FROM @TABLE
SET ROWCOUNT 0

SELECT * FROM @TABLE
```

If the table has no PK, then ordering won't be guaranteed...

Comment: What if I have clustered index that is not the same as my PK?

Comment: Ah of course, my bad - Then it will be by the first row in the clustered index, as that physically orders the rows, not the PK. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Even then, it's not guaranteed to be the "first" ordered by the clustered index. SQL Server makes no guarantees on this.

Comment: See slide 7 on the following, for example. http://www.google.com/url?sa=U&start=3&q=http://www.microsoft.at/eventsmedia/GetDocument.ashx%3FID%3D58225869-954e-4775-91ae-5c7d27be0d34&ei=PfHdSemxA5y6jAegs4WEDg&usg=AFQjCNFlyoKvRdgkxifjsd3cPugWBO_slA

Comment: I like that PPT, thank you very much. LOL at "NoLock is a cool hint" -  I worked in a place that believed that and would not accept otherwise. I left.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the selected answer, a table source can be used, in this case a derived query:

```
delete from dd
from (
    select top 1 *
    from my_table
) dd
```

Feel free to add orderbys and conditions.

For the next example, I'll assume that the restriction on 'where' is due to not wanting to select a row based on its values.  So assuming that we want to delete a row based on position (in this case the first position):

```
delete from dd
from (
    select
        *,
        row = row_number() over (order by (select 1))
    from my_table
) dd
where row = 1
```

Note that the (select 1) makes it the sort order that the tables or indexes are in.  You can replace that with a newid to get fairly random rows.

You can also add a partition by to delete the top row of each color, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Does this really make sense?
There is no "first" record in a relational database, you can only delete one random record.

Comment: It makes sense when you mix in "order by"; Question doesn't mention not to use "order by", just not "where" and cursors

Comment: Only if you order by a column that is unique. If it's not unique, you still don't know exactly which record you delete.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by «'first' record from a table» ? There's no such concept as "first record" in a relational db, i think.

Using MS SQL Server 2005, if you intend to delete the "top record" (the first one that is presented when you do a simple "*select * from tablename*"), you may use "*delete top(1) from tablename*"... but be aware that this does not assure which row is deleted from the recordset, as it just removes the first row that would be presented if you run the command "*select top(1) from tablename*".

Comment: But which row would appear first could vary between running that select and running the subsequent delete. There are *no* guarantees on ordering without an order by clause.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I think I underlined that in my post. The "top record" may vary. Thanks for your reply, as my English isn't the best and I may have not been clear in my reply.

Answer (score 0):

SQL-92:

```
DELETE Field FROM Table WHERE Field IN (SELECT TOP 1 Field FROM Table ORDER BY Field DESC)
```

Comment: `TOP` is not standard SQL-92. And I definitely see a `where` condition in your answer.