# Are Select Top(n) and Delete Top(n) same?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

If use the select statement:

```
select top (18) * from pippo;
```

And I use the delete statement:

```
delete top (18) from pippo;
```

I would like to know if the 18 selected and deleted rows are the same.
Any help?

EDIT after having accepted the answer:

I have found the following solution here: [Delete the 'first' record from a table in SQL Server, without a WHERE condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733668/delete-the-first-record-from-a-table-in-sql-server-without-a-where-condition)

```
WITH  q AS
        (
        SELECT TOP 18 *
        FROM    pippo
        ORDER BY FIELD1 ASC /* You may want to add ORDER BY here */
        )
DELETE
FROM    q
```

With this solution I sort all the "pippo" table by FIELD1, and then I delete the first 18 rows.

Comment: even if you have an `ORDER BY` clause, you need to ensure that it defines a complete ordering over all rows, or else it will still be poorly defined (e.g. if there are 50 rows where a = `abc`, then `top 18 ... order by a` might pick a different 18 each time)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without an order by clause, there is no guaranteed ordering so no, they are not guaranteed to be the same.

Comment: also there could be other processes, inserting or deleting data. So you're never sure which 18 records are deleted