# How to deleted only 1 rows if next row is the same

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{               
    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter SAD = new SqlDataAdapter("DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE ID_='"+textBox4.Text.ToString() + "'", con);
    SAD.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("DELETE ALREADY!");
    string query = "SELECT * FROM Table1";
    SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SDA.Fill(dt);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    con.Close();                     
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are there duplicate id's?
Is this on test data? Then you can go the SQL Server management Studio and manually delete the row.

And fix the Id field to be unique!

Comment: how can i fix the id field???

Comment: You should encapsule your code in a using block. Also use parameters instead of concatinating strings, as this is a security risk (injection). Depending on your underlying database there are multiple options to delete only one of the entries, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733668/delete-the-first-record-from-a-table-in-sql-server-without-a-where-condition

Comment: Let this be a lesson to always create an `Id` column.

Comment: You should have an unique property in your table an do delete based on this unique property.

Comment: First change the values in the Id_ column to have unique values. Then in the properties of Id_ make it unique. 
Or:
Add an extra Id column that must be unique!
And see if you need to change your code that is creating the rows, to not insert rows where Id_ is the same as an existing one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to delete duplicates but keep only one.
Can you try this ?

```
DELETE FROM Table1
    WHERE ID_ NOT IN
    (
    SELECT ID_
    FROM Table1
    )
```

Comment: If id's in the two rows are the same this does not work.